# what is the best design to use connections in signalr

Tags: signalr

I have some doubts regarding my software design with signalr,

usually I start with this code:

```
   var connection = $.hubConnection();
   var notifier = connection.createHubProxy('notifier');
      connection.start()
          .done(function () {
              //alert('connection was succesful');
              // your event handlers
              });
```

***UPDATED QUESTION***
If you have a common click event handler that will only use signalR to broadcast a message, and this event handler is on a separate javascript file (out of the context of the current connection):

should I open the connection in the external script? or 
should I send a reference of the proxy (already connected) to the external script?

Answer (score 0):

When your page doesn't need a connection you should not open one.

Comment: thanks for the reply @Jan but what happens when you use signalr for a "temporal" persistent connection and then you don't know if you're gonna need it or not? ... should you leave it open just in case you need it again? or should you close it and open another one later? This is because you will be assigned to a connectionId, and I think this is unique to everyone, will I get the same id again?

Comment: When there is any possibility, that the server wants to send data to the client, the connection has to be open - thats the point of signalR. So when you say *don't know* i guess, there is a possibility, that you need it.

Comment: I updated the question, can you help me with the architecture concept? @Jan